# How can you get what the function input in `trace_add` return (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

The callback function that is called when the variable you're listening to is changed / read / etc ... (according to `mode`) is called indeed, but I cannot find a way to get what the function returns. And I want it to modify a variable without having to start my listener with `global my_variable`, as using a global variable here is likely to not be recommended.

The documentation seems to indicate that `callback` can return stuff (the type-hinting doesn't specify `-> None` but `-> Any`. Cf. below:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type hint showing `-> str` means `trace_add` will return a `str`, which means, when you store what `trace_add` returns it will be a string. It does **not** refer to the return value from `callback` argument supplied to it:

```
abc = var.trace_add('write', func)
print(abc) # Ex: 2761646820160func
```

Which will store the name of the callback.

And you cannot use what `func` returns, because it is a callback. You might want to use `global var_name` inside `func` to use the variable name elsewhere rather than returning it.

Comment: What is `the name of the callback`, the name  of the function?

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows Yes, name of the function and the memory location I assume

Comment: So we can never get what a `callback` function returns?

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows If have to say, no. I am not really sure, some googling on it might help

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows Why should you retrieve something other than a ref of the trace by adding one? In your defined function you can call other functions that can return a value.

Comment: @Thingamabobs Well I wanted my callback function to return a value. My callback function does call other functions that return a value in the scope of my callback function. But none can return a value in the scope of where `trace_add` is called. To do that I ended up using GLOBAL VARIABLES. I feel like it's decently readable though so it should be fine.

Comment: It is impossible to get the result of the callback. The callback happens sometime in the future, and is called by the underlying tcl interpreter. There is no way to retrieve the value.

Comment: _"Well I wanted my callback function to return a value."_ - since the callback is called at some indeterminate time in the future, where do you expect the value to be returned to?

Comment: `var.trace_add('write', func)` means "**when `var` is written to**, call `func`". We can't find out "in the scope of where `trace_add` is called" what the return value of `func` is, because `func` **is not called** in that scope. It's setting up something that will happen later. The caller of `func` will **not be any function in your own code**, but instead something in the Tkinter internals. You won't be able to see the return value from `func`, because it is returned **to something that is not under your control** (and which in fact has been designed to ignore it).